# Add up two algebraic numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, polynomials

### Definitions

- An algebraic number is a number that is a zero of a non-zero polynomial with integer coefficients. For example, the square root of `2` is algebraic, because it is a zero of `x^2 - 2`.
- The corresponding polynomial is called the minimal polynomial of the algebraic number, provided that the polynomial is irreducible over `ℚ`.

### Task

Given the minimal polynomials of two algebraic numbers, construct a set of numbers that are the sum of two numbers, one from the root of one polynomial, and one from the other. Then, construct a polynomial having those numbers as roots. Output the polynomial. Note that all roots are to be used, **including complex roots**.

### Example

- The two roots of `x^2-2` are `√2` and `-√2`.
- The two roots of `x^2-3` are `√3` and `-√3`.
- Pick one from a polynomial, one from the other, and form 4 sums: `√2+√3`, `√2-√3`, `-√2+√3`, `-√2-√3`.
- A polynomial containing those four roots is `x^4-10x^2+1`

### Input

Two polynomials in any reasonable format (e.g. list of coefficients). They will have degree at least `1`.

### Output

One polynomial in the same format, with **integer coefficients**.

You are **not** required to output an irreducible polynomial over `ℚ`.

### Testcases

Format: input, input, output.

```
x^4 - 10 x^2 + 1
x^2 + 1
x^8 - 16 x^6 + 88 x^4 + 192 x^2 + 144

x^3 - 3 x^2 + 3 x - 4
x^2 - 2
x^6 - 6 x^5 + 9 x^4 - 2 x^3 + 9 x^2 - 60 x + 50

4x^2 - 5
2x - 1
x^2 - x - 1

2x^2 - 5
2x - 1
4x^2 - 4 x - 9

x^2 - 2
x^2 - 2
x^3 - 8 x
```

The outputs are irreducible over `ℚ` here. However, as stated above, you do not need to output irreducible polynomials over `ℚ`.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Would you mind making your first test case a worked example? The second polynomial only has imaginary roots, and I'm not sure what implications this has wrt your challenge.

Comment: @LuisMendo what should the answer be?

Comment: @Dennis I already have a worked example...

Comment: I'm aware of that. You don't mention complex roots anywhere though.

Comment: @LeakyNun I get `4*x^2 - 4*x - 9`, but I'm not sure

Comment: @LuisMendo culpa mea.

Comment: @Dennis I've added the clarification.

Comment: @LuisMendo added.

Comment: Your spec currently seems to allow cases like `x^2-2` and `x^2-8`, or even `x^2-2` and `x^2-2` again. Can you (either prohibit these or) add corresponding test cases?

Comment: @GregMartin testcase added.

Comment: Your last test's output has only three zeros, is this an oversight or do we have to merge repeated roots of the intermediate result during our simplification ...or is `x^4-8x^2` acceptable too (like Luis' answer is yielding)?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I'm assuming that's what the comment about irreducible polynomials is referring to. So, you can do either.

Comment: Come to think of it, an irreducible polynomial is quite stronger than just merging roots. I don't think it always is the case that you *can* give an irreducible polynomial, because e.g. one of the root sums could be `0`. Example: `x^2+x+1` and `x^2-x+1`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I think a definition would help - I have never come across the term before anyway!

Comment: @JonathanAllan It means that the polynomial is not a product of two polynomials of smaller degree > 0, with rational coefficients. A polynomial with duplicated (complex) roots is never irreducible, but irreducible is stronger in general.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Ah thanks. So infinity many outputs are acceptable then (e.g. double all the coefficients). I do think things like this should be defined in specifications otherwise they're open to misinterpretation.

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, 32 bytes

```
Resultant[#,#2/.x->z-x,x]/.z->x&
```

Or the same length:

```
Resultant[#/.x->y,#2/.x->x-y,y]&
```

#### Example:

```
In[1]:= Resultant[#,#2/.x->z-x,x]/.z->x&[x^4 - 10 x^2 + 1, x^2 + 1]

Out[1]= 144 + 192 x^2 + 88 x^4 - 16 x^6 + x^8

In[2]:= Resultant[#/.x->y,#2/.x->x-y,y]&[x^2 - 2, x^2 - 2]

Out[2]= -8 x^2 + x^4
```

#### Explanation:

If `x` is a root of `f(x)`, `y` is a root of `g(y)`, and let `z = x + y`, then `(x, z)` is a root of the simultaneous equations `f(x) = 0, g(z - x) = 0`. Then we can eliminate the variable `x` using the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant).

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>81</s> 71 bytes

*10 bytes off thanks to [Suever](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51939/suever)!*

```matlab
@(a,b){[~,d]=rat(x=poly((roots(a)+roots(b)')(:)')),round(x*prod(d))}{2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#S7PV09P776CRqJOkWR1dp5MSa1uUWKJRYVuQn1OpoVGUn19SrJGoqQ1hJGmqa2pYAQlNnaL80rwUjQqtgqL8FI0UTc3aaqPa/2ka0YYKBgq6hgZA0jBWRwHMNYzV5ALL6BorGCvomsDEdY0gEiYgtilI1AioFSJmhEUMqgdJ938A)

#### Explanation

The code defines an anonymous function which uses a straightforward approach. It obtains the roots of each polynomial, computes all pairwise sums, and converts back from roots to polynomial. Since the resulting coefficients may not be integer, each is converted to a rational approximation and then they are all multiplied by the product of denominators.

Comment: You can shave off a number of bytes by using an anonymous function instead: `@(a,b){[~,d]=rat(x=poly((roots(a)+roots(b)')(:)')),round(x*prod(d))}{2}`

Comment: @Suever Thanks! I forgot that indexing trick

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), <s>50</s> 49 bytes

```
p->q->polresultant(subst(p,x,y),subst(q,x,x-y),y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pari-gp#fYxBCoQwDADvviLHxG1grd2jPkVwYQVBtNoK9fU12BU9eUomGaaDCqLleubaTsPyc@vg29GjW7/Oo1VBbaQSzAKBBTeKdulF6jA0BhiKdx4aDS8oCM@FssspxSn/ikwhk0QGfRNNnm4fQn1Y94p@ep6tKxp3)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
Ærp/S€Æṛær9µ÷g/Ḟ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@3@4rahAP/hR05rDbQ93zj68rMjy0NbD29P1H@6Y9////2hdIx0DHcNYHRgDAA) (runs the last test case)

Takes input as list of coefficients with lowest value exponent first, e.g. `[-5,0,2],[-1,2]` would be `2x^2-5,2x-1`

**Explanation**

```
Ærp/S€Æṛær5µ÷g/Ḟ
Ær                 - get roots of input polynomial
  p/               - Cartesian product (all pairs) of roots
    S€             - sum of each pair
      Æṛ           - find a polynomial given the sums as the roots
        ær9        - round to 10^(-9), used for output
           µ÷      - divide by ... 
             g/    - the gcd of the coefficients of the output polynomial
               Ḟ   - take the floor to get integers.
```

Comment: `Ær - get roots of input polynomial` How do you beat Jelly if it can solve polynomials in 2 bytes... :(

Comment: @JungHwanMin Write a Mathematica package that redefines the verbose function names to one letter and call it your Mathematica golf language. It's as simple as that. The *get roots of polynomial* is actually `lambda z: listify(numpy.roots(z[::-1]))`. It's no criticism since I like the idea of creating a golfing language, but it misses the point. When I see this right JungHwan you were the first with the `Im[I^#]&` solution for the triangle signal. This is what I call creativity!